# bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() returns a 'not found' error in socket_filter type of bpf program in Linux 04.04.15

Tags: bpf, ebpf

I have a bpf program of the socket_filter type.
Trying to get the PID of the process involved in the current packet.
Then it will go into a bpf map for the user space to use.
However, this call does not work ; the function is not found.

Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic
Linux 04.15

Answer (score 2):

The `bpf_get_current_pid_tgid` is [not currently allowed](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.8/source/net/core/filter.c#L6134) for `BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER` programs.

What is your use case for this? If you have a strong use case, the kernel would probably accept a patch adding support for it.

Comment: Thanks:) Please point me to docs that state this. I calculate statistics etc in the bpf code and place them in the map. The user space program reads them and further enriches them with additional info. Knowing the PiD involved in a connection makes it easy for the user space program to do this. Is there any other way to acheive the same thing ?

Comment: There is no documentation that states this AFAIK. In any case, the code is a source of truth (whereas the docs could be out of date).

Comment: I can't see another way to achieve what you want with the program type you are using. I'd suggest switching to another BPF hook if that's possible for you.

Comment: There _is_ [this document](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/kernel-versions.md#program-types) about helpers' availability, but it's directly inferred from the source file pointed by pchaigno. And he's right, the doc may get outdated and kernel code prevails.

Comment: Thanks...helps a lot
Couple of questions
1. Would the cookie help ? 
2. As I need to see the packet, do you suggest any other hook that will allow me to do so
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello there @ShridharV I've just bumped in a similar problem. I'm parsing packets with socket_filter and would also like to get the PID of the process who made the socket. Did you eventually find a workaround? Or did you use a different helper?